# How to make UUID auto generated in springbok Cassandra app

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra, java-19

I am using

Java: 19

Springboot: 3.0

Dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Entity class

```
@Table
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {
  @PrimaryKey
  private UUID id;
```

Would like to know if there is anything like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

that we can use with it.

Comment: Just generate it yourself on the client.

Comment: @M.Deinum for now I am doing it, but searching for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TIMEUUID)
```

is not auto generating the id.

One way is assigning default during declaration value like

```
 private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

but still, I consider this as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved either using **@CassandraType** annotation in combination with the **com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.Name.UUID**

```
@Table
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {
  @PrimaryKey
  @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UUID)
  private UUID id;
```

or
**@CassandraType** annotation with the **com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.Name.TIMEUUID**

```
@Table
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {
  @PrimaryKey
  @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TIMEUUID)
  private UUID id;
```

Comment: `@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name` Name is not available for import, already tried this one.

Comment: check this file have definition-->CassandraRowMapperFn.java

Comment: Can you please let me know your dependency seems you are using different package my DataType class is under `import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.DataType;`

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/overview-summary.html

package:com.datastax.driver.core

it's DataStax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra - Binary distribution 2.0.12 API

Comment: It needs another package `cassandra-driver-mapping` and that will change all the other syntax in my entity class.

Comment: `Incompatible types. Found: 'com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.Name', required: 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraType.Name'` the below option what I have posted is working, but still tried your version with `.cassandra.core.mapping` package and still getting this error, do you have any information which may help on it?